# Replacing a value in xml file with ANT task

Tags: xml, ant

I would like to replace the value of an `xml` element via an `ANT` task....what is the best way to achieve this?

**Example:**  `abc.xml` contains an element `<setpath> true </setpath>`. I would like to replace the value of `<setpath>` as `false` via an `ANT` task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [replace](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) or [replaceRegexp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) task, or, if really needed, using the [xslt](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html) task.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet! for the benefit of others here is what I did....        <replaceregexp file=".../abc.xml"
                 match="setpath>true"
                 replace="setpath>false"
                 byline="true"
/>